# Firebase Storage throwing error on image upload (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an application that invites users to upload image files, which I then intend to store using Firebase's Cloud Storage. I've gotten pretty far using the Firebase docs, but I keep getting a 400 response when I try to upload the files.

Here is the component from which users upload their files:

```
class JobEntry extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="single-job-entry">
            <div className="job-item">
              <span className="job-item-label">Add doc?:</span>
              <input type="file"  
                id={this.props.id +"file"} 
                data-id={this.props.id} 
                onChange={this.props.submitDoc} />
            </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default JobEntry;
```

And here is the function that uploads the files to Firebase ('storage' and 'resumes' are firebase storage refs):

```
  submitDoc (e) {
    let jobId = e.target.dataset.id
    let id = this.props.userId
    let file = document.getElementById(jobId + 'file').files[0]

    var newPath = storage.resumes.child(jobId + '/' + file.name)

    newPath.put(file).then(snapshot => {
      console.log('Uploaded file')
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message)
    })

  }
```

Every time I try to upload a files, I get this error:

```
Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response.
```

I've checked the server response and there's nothing there that seems to point to the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you manually add a file to storage, are you able to download it? The error isn't very specific so I'm trying to guess. Also, I would try to use `storage.child(...)` without `.resumes`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to activate storage within the Firebase UI before I could interact with via Node. Derp. Good to know though if you're starting to work with Firebase. Couldn't find any mention of it in their documentation.